# Exchange a unique string between smartphones (android & ios) in proximity constantly in background

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I want to write an app that when installed makes the smartphone broadcast a unique string to other smartphones using the app. So the app shall broadcast and check for broadcasts constantly in the background while not draining to much energy. I'd like to implement the app in Flutter. So if you could suggest a plugin or a native android/ios api that is suited for this usecase I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Doing what you describe is possible but it is on the far edge of what operating systems allow requiring heavy use of native-specific techniques.  A Flutter-specific solution may not exist.  Here is a native solution that works in iOS and Android http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2020/05/07/hacking-the-overflow-area

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this. I read through it and from what I can grasp this is sadly way to complex to implement for a side project with my skillset. But at least now I know that I should stop trying.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial